# IE8 @font-face is not working when define not only eot

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

In this case everything works well and font displayed right:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriRegular';
    src: url('fonts/calibri.eot');
}
```

But when I add other formats, font is not displayed in IE8:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriRegular';
    src: url('fonts/calibri.eot');
    src: url('fonts/calibri.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/calibri.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/calibri.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/calibri.svg#CalibriRegular') format('svg');
}
```

What's the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a hash, usually `?#iefix` for convention, on the eot that appears in the multiple src list. 
This explains why: 
[How does ?#iefix solve web fonts loading in IE6-IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050640/how-does-iefix-solve-web-fonts-loading-in-ie6-ie8)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CalibriRegular';
    src: url('fonts/calibri.eot');
    src: url('fonts/calibri.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/calibri.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/calibri.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/calibri.svg#CalibriRegular') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I've used `@font-face` in the past I've used the following;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'webfontregular';
    src: url('../fonts/font.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/font.svg#webfontregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

The only difference I can see is the `#iefix` appended to the end of the second `.eot` declaration. Does this fix it for you? I've never had issues with IE7+ using this.