# What is the best way to include custom font using CSS to make it compatible with maximum browsers?

Tags: html, css, fonts, embed, font-face

I have tried various codes to embed custom font and finally following seems to work in FF & IE8 above. But it does not support in IE7.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'xyzfont';
src: url('fonts/abc-font.eot?') format('eot'), 
     url('fonts/abc-font.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('fonts/abc-font.ttf') format('truetype');
}

h1, h2, h3, div span { font-family: 'xyzfont', Georgia, Arial; }
```

Any suggestion to make it more compatible (such as IE7) most welcome.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax). might help you.

Comment: thanks Mr_Green, link is looking good :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the css i use to embed my font in every browser, hope that helps:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'xyzfont';
src: url('fonts/abc-font.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('fonts/abc-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('fonts/abc-font.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('fonts/abc-font.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('fonts/abc-font.svg#svgFontName') format('svg') /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Also note, that you can set your font family without quote, like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, div span { font-family: xyzfont, Georgia, Arial; }
```

You can learn about font browser support [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/download-embed-fonts-font-face/).

[fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) is probably the best place to generate every font format you need.

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150102141618/http://www.fluorcow.com/embedding-fonts-on-a-website) explain how to find your font ID to add after the hashtag for the SVG font.

If someone is asking why is there `?#iefix` for IE6-IE8 browsers eot font, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636675/2774496).

Comment: thanks morgul, working well in IE-7/8. Even my code also seems to working fine ;) many thanks anyway

Comment: This is the only correct answer to be given to this question, works like a charm! :)

Comment: Wow, fontsquirrel.com is spectacular! Pretty much a web fonts silver bullet. I grabbed a .ttf file from Windows for a font I liked, uploaded it, and it did all the work for me. Very nice. Even gives you direction on dealing with IIS MIME type issues with .svg fonts.

Answer (score 1):

i use this code ;)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BBadr';
    src: url('fonts/BBadr/BBadr.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('fonts/BBadr/BBadr.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
      url("fonts/BBadr/BBadr.otf") format("opentype"), /* Open Type Font */
      url('fonts/BBadr/BBadr.woff') format('woff'),/* Pretty Modern Browsers */
      url('fonts/BBadr/BBadr.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
      url('fonts/BBadr/BBadr.ttf')  format('truetype'),/* Safari, Android, iOS */
      url('fonts/BBadr/BBadr.svg#BBadr') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

you can convert Online youre font ( ttf ( with this website :
[Simple Online Web Font Converter: ttf otf woff woff2 eot svg otf with css stylesheet](https://font-converter.net/en)

Convert font and use my css code  ( not use the sample css of site )

Comment: The site you linked seems to have a history of spamming here. Is it an integral part of your answer? If not, I'd suggest not including a link to it.