# UTF-8 greek chars show incorectly on android

Tags: android, html, encoding, utf-8

im building this site:

http://flou.sait-a.gr/

and i have the following problem:

on some older android devices, some greek chars (usually the ones with a tone, for example: έ) display as a box with an x inside, on PC everything works well. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a font issue.  The box-with-an-x means the device does not have a font installed that supports the Unicode character being displayed.

Also, your site pages are using HTML5 (as evident by use of `<!DOCTYPE html>`), but instead of using HTML5's `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag, they are using HTML4's `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` tag instead.  You should not even be using that tag in HTML5.  Thankfully, your webserver is reporting `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in the HTTP header of each page, otherwise HTML5 browsers might not interpret them as UTF-8 correctly.  You need to fix your `<meta>` tags.  Don't mix HTML4 and HTML5 on the same page.

Comment: I changed the encoding charset, still the chars show incorectly, how can i fix it? im using roboto and im sure it has greek letters

Comment: @K.Lykoudis: I was not suggesting the HTML encoding was *the* problem, just *a* problem. The *real* problem is that you are using a Unicode character that the device web browser's default font simply does not support. You will have to make your HTML/CSS specify an alternative font that does support the character. Or use an [embedded webfont](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871680/) in your HTML.