# Hawtio not starting

Tags: java, hawtio

I am trying to update my hawtio from 1.2.0 to 1.4.4 but I am getting a exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-9950-hawtio-default-offline-1.4.4.war-_ccf-any-\webapp\app\themes\fonts\Open-Sans\OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot?
>   (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

I am deploying hawtio in my jetty server (8.1.14) and I am running on Windows. I have also tried hawtio 1.3.0 and it's working fine. From version 1.4.0 to 1.4.4 none of them work and they throw the mentioned exception. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: What browser are you using?  Looks like the browser is requesting the source URL including the '?' for the .eot file and jetty is trying to resolve that to the local filesystem path without stripping off the '?', which would be invalid on Windows.

The stylesheet for that font follows the guidance here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050640/how-does-iefix-solve-web-fonts-loading-in-ie6-ie8

Though not sure which is at fault here, the browser or Jetty.

Comment: I am using Chrome. I will try in a linux box and see the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be [a bug](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1381) in Hawt.io. There is an indication that it should be fixed in 1.4.5 or 1.4.6, however I have verified that it's still failing in 1.4.8 and 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.