# Concat query string to font-face url

Tags: css, font-face, font-family

To avoid browser's cache, I want to concat version querystring to my `@font-face`'s url. There are lots of urls. How to this in right way?

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'fontawesome';
   src: url('/styles/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.eot?6840zz');
   src: url('/styles/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.eot?6840zz#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/styles/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.ttf?6840zz') format('truetype'),
        url('/styles/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.woff?6840zz') format('woff'),
        url('/styles/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.svg?6840zz#icomoon') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: 2 things I want to ask : you want fontawesome.eot?6840zz it should be like fontawesome.eot?v=1.1.0 some version. Secondly how many files do you have and which IDE you are using ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan What's `68400zz` in query string? Maybe there's a logic behind it. And how IDE can be related to all of this?

Comment: I was thinking if you can find & replace option and add version to all these sort of links. Is not that way ?

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to replace. All I want is to understand the logic behind those magic numbers (68400z) and hashes(#iefix), how they are related to urls and how to add version. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Ah ok right. Well those version number or the code 6840z or any thing is to mention the build number. in case of version number we add ver=1 or 1.1 or 1.1.1 means we are working on the build number 1 and having minor fixes. when we will work on next sprint or build its version will start from ver=2. Regarding code, its a random number generated from that version number to just make separate.

Comment: Thanks, what about the `#iefix` and other hashes?

Comment: Well, that is also a code to manage versions. For reference of hash tag : https://www.electrictoolbox.com/download-embed-fonts-font-face/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most implementations of Font Awesome will append versioned query strings to the `@font-face` font paths. These versioned query strings will bust the cache when the font is updated to a new version. That is, when you update the font the versioned query string will change from something like `?v=4.7.0` to `?v=4.7.1`.

In most cases you won't need to do anything extra as most implementations will handle this for you. Keep in mind, many other `@font-face` generators and packages will also append a version param. Here are a few examples:

1. **Download the Font Awesome kit**

   If you download the Font Awesome kit from http://fontawesome.io/ the included `font-awesome.css` file will have versioned query strings attached to the paths. Ex.

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
     src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

   the `?v=4.7.0` is the versioned query string. This version number will change if you download a new version of Font Awesome down the road.
2. **Font Awesome CDN**

   If you use the CDN implementation you'll get a `<script>` to include, like

   This will import the following CSS:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     src: url('//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
     src: url('//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

   The URLs to the Font Awesome CDN has the version number included, and this will change when updated, breaking the cache and eliminating the need for appending a versioned query parameter.
3. **Using Sass or Less**

   If you're using the Less/Sass files the versioned query string will be added. Ex.

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=@{fa-version}');
     src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=@{fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=@{fa-version}') format('woff2'),
       url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=@{fa-version}') format('woff'),
       url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=@{fa-version}') format('truetype'),
       url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=@{fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
     // src: url('@{fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
   }
   ```

   The `@{fa-version}` will append the current version (currently `4.7.0` to the font path. This version number will update when the font is updated. In this sense you can update all the version query params at once by changing the `fa-version` variable.

**#iefix**

Regarding the `#iefix` hash, this is a method of fixing an issue in IE8 and below when defining multiple font formats within a single `src`. If you need your font to work in IE8 and below you need to add the `#iefix` (or any hash`) so those browsers don't throw errors. More on that in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050640/how-does-iefix-solve-web-fonts-loading-in-ie6-ie8).

**Other @font-face Fonts and Implementations**

If you're using a font other than Font Awesome, or another implementation, you can append a hash onto the font paths to create your own cache-bust. It's fairly common to see a date string appended, like `01302017`, which can be updated manually or via a build script when needed.

Comment: Anything I can add to increase my chances of getting that elusive green check? ;)

Comment: Sure, I have just forgotten ;)

Comment: Hi, does this query string is needed when we use preload with font url?
<link rel="preload" src="fonts/customicons/icomoon.ttf?b4x7s" type="font/ttf" /> ???