# Why Font-face no work on IE 11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face, bootstrap-4

i'm creating this Web Site: http://94.177.167.40/gmmcorporate
But my css no work on IE 11 (11.608.15063.0).
It's not take correctly font-face and dropdown menu after.
Can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Explorer traditionally has some issues with Truetype fonts. They should be supported since IE9, but it seems like there has to be a special bit set, to make the font "installable", as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711769/3775858).

Now you could try to solve this, or you convert your fonts to the `.eot` format, and use them as a fallback for IE like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Noyh-Geometric';
    src: url('fonts/Noyh-Geometric.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Noyh-Geometric?#iefix') format('eot'),
         url('fonts/Noyh-Geometric.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You propably can omit the line with the `?#iefix` ending, since this was only relevant for IE6-8, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636675/3775858). Give it a try, and let me know, if this was helpful.